# Remove one item from flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using FlatList to show a list of data.
I was trying dozens of example how to remove one row from data, but couldn't find the right solution.

Right now I'm removing all data from state, but I want to remove just one item.

Here is my HomeScreen which displays list of data:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: data.products
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Products"
  };

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

  openDetails = data => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", {
      data
    });
  };

  deleteItem = data => {
    this.setState({ data: ''})
  }

  renderProduct = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <Item
        itemTitle={item.title}
        openDetails={() => this.openDetails(item)}
        itemUrl={item.imageUrl}
        data={this.state.data}
        deleteItem={() => this.deleteItem(item)}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this.renderProduct}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Here is my Item component which is showing one item and receiving deleteRow function as prop:

```
const Item = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.deleteItem}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: props.itemUrl }}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: 220 }}
        />
        <Text style={styles.productTitle}>{props.itemTitle}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Answer (score 6):

Use below `deleteItem` function.

```
deleteItem = data => {
  let allItems = [...this.state.data];
  let filteredItems = allItems.filter(item => item.id != data.id);
  this.setState({ data: filteredItems })
}
```

This should filter out the deleted item.

Comment: Nothing is happening when I click on remove

Comment: To flatlist add another prop extraData={this.state}

Comment: added extraData={this.state.data} but still same thing, looks like you're no right way, but it's not working yet

Comment: Just to be sure looking at your keyExtractor function, each product object has an id property? Could you add console.log to deleteItem before and after filter to verify item is removed.

Comment: Each object has id (from 1 to 9). Console.log before filter is showing same array as after filter

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot. I didn't get the right console.log because setState is async